# The size of the FrameLayout's child is larger than its parent

Tags: android, layout, view, android-framelayout

The problem is my `FrameLayout`'s child draw and show larger than its parent, Through seeing the source code of `FrameLayout`, I still have no idea about the reason, If anyone knows solution or other details about this, Let me know.

For Layout Hierarchy and snapshot please see the below image.

```
FrameLayout(Parent)
  - FrameLayout(Child, that should NOT be larger than its parent)
    - View
```

adb shell dumpsys activity top:

```
android.widget.LinearLayout{ed38a19 V.E...... ......I. 0,0-1080,1920}
      android.view.ViewStub{c7b9ade G.E...... ......I. 0,0-0,0 #10203aa android:id/action_mode_bar_stub}
      android.widget.FrameLayout{f84c4bf V.E...... ......I. 0,0-1080,1920 #1020002 android:id/content}
        com..startup.VideoBaseLayout{d290df4 V.E...... ......I. 0,0-1080,1920}
          com..view.PaddingFrameLayout{a4aeddb V.E...... ......I. 0,0-1080,1620}
            com..view.PlayerViewSurface{a436351 V.E...C.. ......I. 0,-1179-1080,2799}
              android.view.SurfaceView{89a27b6 V.E...... ......I. 0,0-1080,3978}
              android.widget.ImageView{e808cb7 G.ED..... ......I. 0,0-0,0}
          android.widget.TextView{f3e2b89 V.ED..C.. ......I. 804,48-1032,145}
```

[image]

Comment: @Alex Wang post your xml

Comment: @Charuක I add those views by java codes in runtime, not xml. and Child has not set LayoutParameter, and Father is MATCH_PARENT both for width and height.

Comment: what is the output of `adb shell dumpsys activity top` when you run your app?

Comment: @pskink sorry, I didn't get the point.

Comment: run `adb shell dumpsys activity top` on your terminal, what is the output of that command?

Comment: PS: View that the last child is a SurfaceView.

Comment: post your code?

Comment: @Krish the code segment is kind of complicate..

Comment: @pskink I post the infomation about layout, please check it.

Comment: so your `FrameLayout` is `android.widget.FrameLayout{f84c4bf V.E...... ......I. 0,0-1080,1920` and its child view is `com..startup.VideoBaseLayout{d290df4 V.E...... ......I. 0,0-1080,1920}` both are 1080 x 1920

Comment: @pskink PaddingFrameLayout is father and PlayerViewSurface is child, and I think PlayerViewSurface 's display height should be less or equal to its father's height.

Comment: i have no idea what `PaddingFrameLayout` is

Comment: @pskink please see dump-info, PaddingFrameLayout is also a FrameLayout.

Comment: it is a custom `FrameLayout` so i have no idea what it overrides, `ScrollView` is also a `FrameLayout` but its main purpose is to scroll the bigger child view

Comment: @pskink It is a custom View, you mean it may cause render problem such as drawing over father's border, if I change the layout phase's behaviour of PaddingFrameLayout's child ？

Comment: yes,  it can,  what do you need it that custom view for?